# How to execute a functionality without button in android?

Tags: java, android, networking, android-activity, client

Now This Code Is Not Working

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


String X = "Music"; 
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


 new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            Socket socket = null;
             DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;
             DataInputStream dataInputStream = null;

             try {
              socket = new Socket("172.16.82.131", 8888);
              dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
              dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
              dataOutputStream.writeUTF(X);
              //textIn.setText(dataInputStream.readUTF());
             } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
              // TODO Auto-generated catch block
              e.printStackTrace();
             } catch (IOException e) {
              // TODO Auto-generated catch block
              e.printStackTrace();
             }
             finally{
              if (socket != null){
               try {
                socket.close();
               } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
               }
              }

              if (dataOutputStream != null){
               try {
                dataOutputStream.close();
               } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
               }
              }

              if (dataInputStream != null){
               try {
                dataInputStream.close();
               } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
               }
              }
             }


            return null;
        }
    }.execute();




   }


    }
```

In My Earlier post i posted a code in which a functionality was being executing on button click but now i have changed my code to this one.
I Tried This Method for Running My code in Background on launching the application.. but nothing happpens. I Am Not Able to find where i am going wrong.. Please Help :(

Comment: just write you method in oncreate

Comment: add the click event code in onCreate() Method. It will execute on launch.

Comment: i don't understand what you have tried and what doesn't work.

Comment: Don't modify your question midstream please.  It causes confusion.  Please provide a LogCat output of any errors.  Get rid of the e.printStackTrace() and actually log the errors to LogCat with Log.e("someString", "unknownhost", e); etc.

Answer (score 1):

Rename onClick() to something else, remove the button and the click listeners.  Then it's going to fail because you're making a networking call on the UI thread.  You're going to need to use an AsyncTask() (or similar.)

If you just want it to run and don't care about the answer ...

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // ...
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try {
                // your code here
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // catch any errors
            }
            return null;
        }
    }.execute();
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Can You Explain How can I implement AsyncTask in My Code..Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
public class AndroidClient extends Activity {  

        String x = "Music";
             /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         textIn = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textin);
      doThis();

    }                
       public void doThis() {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     Socket socket = null;
     DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;
     DataInputStream dataInputStream = null;

     try {
     socket = new Socket("112.13.835.187", 8183);
     dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
     dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
     dataOutputStream.writeUTF(x);
     textIn.setText(dataInputStream.readUTF());
     } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
     } catch (IOException e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
     }
     finally{
     if (socket != null){
     try {
     socket.close();
     } catch (IOException e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
      }
     }

     if (dataOutputStream != null){
     try {
     dataOutputStream.close();
     } catch (IOException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
     }
     }

     if (dataInputStream != null){
      try {
       dataInputStream.close();
      } catch (IOException e) {
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       e.printStackTrace();
       }
       }
       } 
       }};
    }
```

Comment: Nothing Happens When I Do like This :(

Comment: This code will only work on older Android devices.  You cannot execute networking tasks on the UI thread.  The checkmark was awarded a little too quickly it would seem.

Comment: It probably "doesn't work" because you're catching the exception and it's not going to execute on the UI thread.  See answer below for use of an AsyncTask().

Answer (score 1):

Write your code in onCreate or you can also use [Asynctask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for background process

Answer (score 1):

Use AsyncTask to work with **DataOutputStream and Socket**

See below example code

Call the below line from onCreate() method

```
 new SignInService().execute();
```

And then create class like below and wrtie this line in **onPostExecute method** `textIn.setText(dataInputStream.readUTF());`

```
private class SignInService extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
      Socket socket = null;
      DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;
      DataInputStream dataInputStream = null;

     @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        try {
            progressDilaog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "",
                    "Loading", true, false);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

     try {
        socket = new Socket("112.13.835.187", 8183);
        dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
          dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
          dataOutputStream.writeUTF(x);

      } catch (UnknownHostException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
      finally{
         if (socket != null){
         try {
            socket.close();
          } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
             e.printStackTrace();
           }
          }

        if (dataOutputStream != null){
          try {
            dataOutputStream.close();
          } catch (IOException e) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                 e.printStackTrace();
          }
        }

        if (dataInputStream != null){
           try {
               dataInputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
             }
        }
      }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        progressDilaog.dismiss();

        textIn.setText(dataInputStream.readUTF());
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont know how to use this in my code.can you please Elaborate . Thanks

Comment: Unfortunatly App Stops Working after it show loading dialog box... :(

Answer (score 1):

you have to write the code of the **onClick()** Function in the **onCreate()** Function of the app. and no need to implement the **onClickListener** function of the button.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code...
Here no need to implement the onclick listener of the button

```
public class AndroidClient extends Activity {

String x = "Music";

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

 Button buttonSend = (Button)findViewById(R.id.send);
 textIn = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textin);
 startonCreate(); 
 }
 public void startonCreate(){
 Socket socket = null;
 DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;
 DataInputStream dataInputStream = null;

 try {
  socket = new Socket("112.13.835.187", 8183);
  dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
  dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
 dataOutputStream.writeUTF(x);
 textIn.setText(dataInputStream.readUTF());
 } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
 e.printStackTrace();
 } catch (IOException e) {
 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
  }
  finally{
  if (socket != null){
 try {
 socket.close();
 } catch (IOException e) {
 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
 e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

}

```
if (dataOutputStream != null){
 try {
 dataOutputStream.close();
 } catch (IOException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
 e.printStackTrace();
 }
 }

 if (dataInputStream != null){
 try {
    dataInputStream.close();
   } catch (IOException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
   }
 }
 } 

 }
}
```